# Evaluate a difference quotient - Pre Calculus Homework

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Evaluate the difference quotient:
$f(x)=x^2-x+1$, $\displaystyle \frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}$, $h\not=0$
I have not been able to solve this problem the farthest I have gotten to is $\displaystyle \frac{h^2+3h+2}{h}$. From what it says in my textbook the answer is $3+h, h\not=0$. The problem is that the textbook gives me the answer but not the worked out solution. If anybody can help with this problem, it would be of great help to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, you made a mistake in your algebra. You should have $\frac{h^2+3h}{h}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h} &=\frac{[(2+h)^2-(2+h)+1]-[2^2-2+1]}{h}\\
&=\frac{[\color{blue}{4}+\color{red}{4h}+h^2\color{blue}{-2}\color{red}{-h}\color{blue}{+1}]-[\color{blue}{4-2+1}]}{h}\\
&=\frac{[h^2+\color{red}{3h}+\color{blue}{3}]-[\color{blue}{3}]}{h}\\
&=\frac{h^2+3h}{h}
\\
&=h+3.\end{align*}